# Programmatically select tab on tablayout crashes app when try to access contents inside selected fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, swiperefreshlayout, android-tablayout

I have TabLayout with ViewPager includes 3 tabs/fragments.

I need to add actions to each fragments everytime it resumes. Everything works correctly when changing fragment using touch, but when I change tab programmatically, app crashes. What should I do to prevent this issue?

**Here is some code to explain more about my issue.**

```
private TabLayout tabLayout;

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    //This part works when first tab is selected
    int chatSelTab = 0;
    TabLayout.Tab selectedTab = tabLayout.getTabAt(chatSelTab);
    selectedTab.select();
}



private void setupTablayout() {
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.persons)));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.groups)));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.online)));

    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount(), this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            Voids.savePreferences(getApplicationContext(), Voids.CHAT_SELECTED_TAB, tab.getPosition());
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                case 1:

                    /* TODO: app crashes here when programmatically select tab nro 1. */

                    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh);
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onRefresh() {
                            // DO MY STUFF
                        }
    });
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}
```

**This is what I get to logcat**

```
08-25 01:20:45.054  31753-31753/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myapp, PID: 31753
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout$OnRefreshListener)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Your app crash 'couse your Swiperefresh is null reference. It is un tab 1.    Could you show me full class please?

Comment: As I said, it works when click on tab or swipe to tab1, but if I programmatically click it, it crashes.

Comment: Of course but you log cat says  Swiperefresh Layout null reference.  Your case 1 is bad! Where are you using your Swiperefresh?  SwiperefreshLayout should be in to fragment (tab sección).

Comment: That swiperefreshLayout is under fragment 1, and it works correctly, Only difference is that I click it programmatically. I understand that it is null, but why it is null when selected from onResume, not manually.

Comment: I need see more code your XML and your class where is viewpager.

Answer (score 0):

If your SwipeRefreshLayout is on `Fragment1`, then why are you doing:

```
SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh);
```

???

You are trying to find the view from your activity's view hierarchy. Even though the Activity works as a Fragment placeholder, the latter's view hierarchy is not included. You need to get the `swipeRefreshLayout` reference from `Fragment1` and handle the logic on it as well.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10785262)

Comment: I am not critiquing, just pointing out the mistake. Please read my answer one more time